# Can't send bytearray via paho-mqtt client.publish(). Socket error

Tags: python, mqtt, mosquitto

I'm trying to send an image over paho-mqtt. I can send a simple string via client.publish() or when not using the paho.client -> client.publish(), but publish.single() my bytearray.

When trying to send the bytearray with client.publish() I get a socket error on my broker and it doesnt send my message (No on_publish call). What am I missing?

```
client = paho.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_publish = on_publish
client.connect(MQTT_BROKER, MQTT_PORT)

f = open("foo.jpg", "rb")
fileContent = f.read()
f.close()
byteArr = bytearray(fileContent)

client.publish("/data", byteArr)   # only works with strings. socket error on broker when using bytearray
# publish.single("/data", byteArr, hostname=MQTT_BROKER) # works with string and bytearray
```

Comment: You haven't started the client loop so if your message is bigger than the MTU it won't work (An image is nearly always going to be way bigger than the MTU)

Comment: So I've tried using client.loop_forever() but it doesnt seem to work. I looked into the publish.single() function. I tried to rebuild it. It uses the user_data but I'm not sure if thats the right way to go as it seems it's more of a once set all messages at the beginning type. My use case is I want to send every x seconds an image and don't want to connect and disconnect all the time. Do I have to start / stop the loop for each transmission?

Comment: Just tried it with the start/stop method. It works althoughI'm not quite sure why and how long I have to sleep in between. Probably till I get a publish completed callback?

Comment: MQTT was never really designed for image sending.  Going by the MQTT spec, the max Payload size is 265M, so most images can't even be sent.  If you are trying to send out an image to multiple clients, I would suggest moving the file to some central file directory, and then just send a path to it in your MQTT payload for the clients to go get it from.

Comment: @JDAllen I'm not sure that is true, MQTT is totally payload agnostic, it just has a limit of 256mb per message. Unless you are shooting raw images they are unlikely to be bigger than 256mb. And distributing them via pub/sub is perfectly fine.

Comment: No, I've got several clients and want them all to send images to a single server/broker that acts as a central directory and uses to image for further processes. The images are around ~300kb. It seems to work for now but I've got to test whats the upper client limit. I'm sending images every 0.5s. Are other protocols better suited for my need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hashed out in the comments

```
def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
  client.disconnect()
  client.stop_loop()

client = paho.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_publish = on_publish
client.connect(MQTT_BROKER, MQTT_PORT)
client.loop_start()

f = open("foo.jpg", "rb")
fileContent = f.read()
f.close()
byteArr = bytearray(fileContent)

client.publish("/data", byteArr)
```

The reason `client.loop_forever()` didn't work is because this is a blocking call that never returns, so assuming you inserted it before the call to `client.publish()` you will never get there.

Comment: Yeah. I figured thats the case. Thanks. I switched to start/stop calls.